# .htaccess temporarily move subfolder then permanantly redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently rebuilding a website which is located on `Server A` and putting the new website on `Server B`.

However, `Server A` has a directory `forum/` which must be moved in its entirety to `Server B` but to a `forum.example.com` subdomain instead of a `forum/` folder.

I need to be able to do the following with `.htaccess`

`Server B`: Redirect all `/forum/*` links temporarily to `/forum-maintenance/`

Once the maintenance is complete:

`Server B`: Redirect all `/forum/*` links permenantly to `forum.example.com/$1`

**Examples**

**Temporary**

`example.com/forum/viewpost.php?id=1234 ==> example.com/forum-maintenance/`

**Permanent**

`example.com/forum/viewpost.php?id=1234 ==> forum.example.com/viewpost.php?id=1234`

What two .htaccess rules would I need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in `root/.htaccess` **during maintenance**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum/ /forum-maintenance/? [L,R=302]
```

**Post maintenance**, you can have this rule in `root/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ http://forum.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: The .htaccess files will have to be in the root directory so how would I have to change these rules to match the forum/ sub folder?